# How to avoid getting URL encoded paths from URL.getFile()?

Tags: java, url-encoding

I'm having the following problem when trying to get the path of a given resource:

```
    System.out.println("nf="+new File(".").getAbsolutePath());      
    System.out.println("od="+new File(this.getClass().getResource(".").getFile());
```

The output I get is:

```
nf=C:\Users\current user\workspace\xyz\.
od=C:\Users\current%20user\workspace\xyz\bin\something
```

The problem lies with the %20 URL encoding thing.  How to avoid it? Is there a direct way to avoid getting this kind of string in the first place, or should I just run the returned string against some method that will do the URL decoding?

Thanks

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Answer (score 14, accepted):

This is due to a URL handling quirk in the API. You can work around this by **converting the URL string to a URI** first:

```
new URI(this.getClass().getResource(".").toString()).getPath()
```

This will produce a String as follows:

```
"C:\Users\current user\workspace\xyz\bin\something"
```

Comment: uri.getPath() returned null for me. uri.getSchemeSpecificPart() did the trick.

Comment: this.getClass().getResource(".").toURI().getPath() do the job

Answer (score 0):

I'm adding *Mr_Thorynque* comment as an answer as it also works and at least for me seems to be simpler.

```
this.getClass().getResource(".").toURI().getPath()
```