# Uri special character %

Tags: android, uri

I have a builtUri that is appending a String that contains a special character and when I log the final built string it appears wrong.

```
String signature = "D662636E84CD1A4%26";
...
.appendQueryParameter(SIGNATURE, signature)
```

The problem in the final built Uri that is used to connect is that at the end, instead of "%26" it shows "%2526"

Anyone knows how to fix this?

cheers

Comment: What is the purpose of the `%26` there? Looks like you have an encoded `&` there that you should not be having when constructing URL like this.

Comment: The %26 is a security thing to access the API...I have no control on this unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The character '%' is getting url escaped to '%25'.
It's intended behavior, as this is how the character is represented in an url

If you want to prevent it, you might want to check out [How to avoid getting URL encoded paths from URL.getFile()?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8928661/how-to-avoid-getting-url-encoded-paths-from-url-getfile)

Comment: Weird...Coz When I just put the whole URL as a String (for testing), it works just fine. The thing is that I need this "%26" at the end of the signature

Comment: @Makoto Then put '&' character at the end of string instead of '%26'. %26 is the URL encoded version of '&'. Doing this should fix your problem