# How get a resource in Java with a # (hashtag) in the file path?

Tags: java, url, path, uri, classpath

When there is a file called "#" in the resources directory and I execute `getClass().getResource("/#");`, it returns
`file:/T:/IDEA/webfox/target/classes/%23`

The # converted to a %23. How do I prevent this? These methods are not helping:

- `toString()`: `file:/T:/IDEA/webfox/target/classes/%23`
- `toURI()`: `file:/T:/IDEA/webfox/target/classes/%23`
- `toExternalForm()`: `file:/T:/IDEA/webfox/target/classes/%23`
- `getFile()`: `/T:/IDEA/webfox/target/classes/%23`
- `getPath()`: `/T:/IDEA/webfox/target/classes/%23`

My desired output would be: `T:/IDEA/webfox/target/classes/#`

<sup>This is needed because I use a TomCat application which file name is ROOT##1.1. Trying to save into resources ends up like this:</sup>

[image: Example]

Comment: this might help you https://stackoverflow.com/a/8928965/5527433

Comment: @DavidFlorez thanks it worked

Comment: *Never* assume a resource is a file;  there is no guarantee of this, especially if you ever deploy your application as a .jar.  Why do you need it as a file?  Why not just read the URL as a URL?